# CJPEGCreateImageDataWithData allocating a lot of unreleased memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

From using the Allocations instrument to track my app's memory usage I've noticed that throughout the runtime of the app the memory usage keeps going up. Looking through the heapshots I can see that the largest chunks of memory are being allocated by a method called CJPEGCreateImageDataWithData in the library GMM. I can't find anything online about this happening, but it certainly looks like this is responsible for my app's memory-hogging. Here's a screenshot of the pertinent part of the Allocations output:

[image]

What might be the reason for this, and how would I avoid it?

Comment: That's MKMapView caching tiles. What is the iOS version installed?

Comment: I'm using the iPhone 4.0 simulator. Currently I don't have a device to test it on. Does this mean there's nothing I can do about the memory?

Answer (score 1):

The simulator and the device use a different amount of memory due to several factors.
MKMapView should behave well enough on iOS 4.2 or higher. Even when you see a steep memory increase, note that it is cache memory, and all that is not required by MKMapView to work. The only problem is that it may bring your application closer to a low memory warning. You can emulate this warning and see if your app survives. Other than that, you can't control the map cache directly. If you don't have enough memory for your app to work, try using the normal map instead the satellite one.